# Array map method bug with ie 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

here is my code and it work in all browser except IE 7 :

```
var sum = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        .map(function (x) { return parseInt(input[x]) * (10 - x); })
        .reduce(function (x, y) { return x + y; }) % 11;
```

How I can resolve it to work in all browsers.

**Edit:** Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'map'

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using? Version 1.x supports older IE versions.

Comment: I've used [kendo]/[2014.1.416]/jquery.min.js which is 1.9.1 customized version for kendo

Comment: Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'map'

Comment: That is not Jquery `map` method (`$.map`), you are calling `map` method of native array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `map` method of native array, and [IE7 does not have it implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Browser_compatibility) (and the same happens with `reduce`). This is a solution using jQuery functions that should work:

```
var acc = 0;

$.each($.map([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], function(x) {
    return parseInt(input.charAt(x)) * (10 - x);
}), function(key, value) {
    acc = acc + value;
}); 

var sum = acc % 11;
```

Even more, if the keys of `input` are always numbers (and you go through all of them), you could remove the map function having the code like this:

```
var acc = 0;

$.each(input, function(key,value) {
    acc = acc + (parseInt(value) * (10 - key));
});

var sum = acc % 11;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know it doesn't support but your code returns 2 but the sum value for get and reduce function return 1 and actually it is different in result.

Comment: @kamiar3001 before I forgot to add the `input[x]` on that part of the code (I was using just `X`), so maybe that's why it is not working. What are the values in input so I can test it?

Comment: here is my string value "0453657941". it doesn't work again when it hit the compatibility button. the acc value is NaN but in IE 11 it work the same.

Comment: @kamiar3001 Edited answer, the problem was that you can not access the string elements with `[]` at IE7. With `charAt` should work.